# Is that possible to save values generated by Hive UDTF?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created Hive custom UDTF. My new UDTF returns new 3 columns based on input 2 columns.

But, I can't any `INSERT` operation by using generated values.
For example,

- `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'generated_data.csv' SELECT udtf(one, two) FROM table_orig;`
- `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_table SELECT udtf(one, two) FROM table_orig;`

Both of `INSERT` queries returns NullPointerException like following:

```
2017-05-30T08:02:45,209 ERROR [main([])]: exec.Task (:()) - Failed to execute tez graph.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionPoolManager.canWorkWithSameSession(TezSessionPoolManager.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionPoolManager.getSession(TezSessionPoolManager.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionPoolManager.getSession(TezSessionPoolManager.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.execute(TezTask.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2073)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1744)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1161)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you !

Comment: Have you tried this: ` INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_table SELECT udtf(one, two) as (col1, col2, col3) FROM table_orig; ` ?

Comment: (1) `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY` works with directories, not files (2) supply the udtf interface and `test_table` DDL (3) Test on MR, not Tez

Comment: @leftjoin Bingo! Once I append `AS(x, y, z)` after udtf(), it works. Thank you for your comment. Please post your answer ?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thank you also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add columns list after UDTF:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test_table SELECT udtf(one, two) as (col1, col2, col3) FROM table_orig;
```